How to Implement Multilingual Enums in Laravel for API Responses with Translations
I am building an API in Laravel and need to implement enums with multilingual support. For example, I have a CONNECTION_TYPE enum with values like WIRED and WIRELESS. My goal is to display these values in both English and Georgian, depending on the user's locale.
I want to use enums for clean code and type safety, store translations for the enum values using Laravel's localization feature, and return the translated labels in the API response based on the current locale.
What is the best approach to achieve this while adhering to best practices for enums and translations in Laravel? Please share any examples or insights.
I tried defining enums in PHP and using Laravel's __('key') function for translations directly inside the enum. I expected the translated labels to appear in the API response based on the user's locale. However, the implementation felt repetitive and not as clean as I wanted, especially when handling localization for multiple languages. Additionally, I wasn't sure if this approach aligns with best practices.

The best option will be translation files and string-backed enums. Call them using __(CONNECTION_TYPE::WIRED->value);.

and where should i save translations, in json?
also i have one more question if i have many enums what is the preffered way to return them with api?

Use the Laravel Localization docs to get started with translation files. The way it's explained there is the recommended way. You can get all Enum cases using CONNECTION_TYPE::cases(); and I guess you'd just return those in whatever way works for your specific use case.
